# Create a database with sqlalchemy-turbodbc on MSSQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, turbodbc

I am trying to create a database on MSSQL server with sqlalchemy and turbodbc.

Below is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import turbodbc

username = ''
password = ''
server = ''
database = ''
driver= 'ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

con = create_engine(f"mssql+turbodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}:1433/{database}?driver={driver}")

con.execute(f"create database newdb")
```

Error

```
DatabaseError: (turbodbc.exceptions.DatabaseError) ODBC error
state: 42000
native error code: 226
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.
[SQL: create database sai]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

Can somebody help?. I am looking to create a database only by using the modules: SQLALCHEMY, Turbodbc or psycopg2. Due to some restrictions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) docs.

> The CREATE DATABASE statement must run in autocommit mode (the default
>   transaction management mode) and is not allowed in an explicit or
>   implicit transaction.

In SqlAlchemy you can [set autocommit](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit) passing it as parameter like this:

```
engine.execute(text("SELECT my_mutating_procedure()").execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Comment: I am still having the same error. I guess `.execution_options(autocommit=True)` is not working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. This worked for me

```
import turbodbc


connection = turbodbc.connect(
                                driver=driver , server=server , database=database,
                                uid=username , pwd=password,
                            )
connection.autocommit =True
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("create database newdb")
```